# Google Spreadsheet in an iframe opens in htmlview mode instead edit mode in smaller screens?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, mobile

I have a Google spreadsheet file where the users needs to edit using the tablet. Since the ipad/tablet chrome doesn't support image buttons with script, I have embedded the spreadsheet in a webapp html using an iframe.

The iframe url is a /edit url. When the webapp is run using a laptop, it works well, but after I open using a ipad or mobile the iframe is loaded with htmlView url automatically even though the sheet has edit URL.

How do I force the iframe to load the edit url of the sheet in any device.

**iPAD/Mobile view**

[image]

**Laptop or desktop view**

[image]

I have tried with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

<h3>This is test1</h3>
    <style>
        iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 1600px;
            background: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100% 100%"><text fill="%23FF0000" x="50%" y="50%" font-family="\'Lucida Grande\', sans-serif" font-size="24" text-anchor="middle">Loading...</text></svg>') 0px 0px no-repeat;
        }
    </style>

<iframe class="second-row" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1usDFz5VnURHYodpT6A9HGFKSHx65ATU1_0Qml2-hAec/edit?&rm=minimal" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
    function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Google Sheets is detecting the browser user agent and switching to htmlview for mobile devices. It used to be the case until recently that you could [use `?overridemobile=true` and then `?fd=true`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/70537) after the edit url to force desktop but this parameter is now ignored.

In the Chrome browser the user agent can be modified from the setting to specify 'Desktop site' but this would have to be selected each time the user wanted to click an image button.

Within a Google Apps Script it is possible to `[getUserAgent()][2]`, but no method to set the user agent.

Going down the `iframe` route in older browsers it was possible to modify the user agent but that option has been closed with improved browser security.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I understand that there is no way in an iframe as well.